# randomly make directories with random names - vbs

Tags: vbscript

I have a folder with massive number of files, i need to make some folders and put them in to that folders (below 50 of each), Folder names can be any thing. I thought folder name to be numbers( 1,2,3.. etc )
here what i done, but doesn't work

```
  Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    inputFldr =".\myFolder"
    Set fldr=fso.getFolder(inputFldr)
    dim i
    i=0
    fName = 0

for each file in fldr.files
    i = i+1
    If Not fso.FolderExists(fName) Then fso.CreateFolder(fName)
    fso.MoveFile file, fName

    if i>50 then
        fName = fName + 1
        i = 0
    end if
next
wscript.echo done
```

Comment: If the `If Not fso.FolderExists(...)` line is really 1 line, remove the `End If` at the end of that line, and put space before and after `&` if you are not working in hexadecimal. But if this is all your code, I doubt it will work as it does not have the actual folder path.

Comment: I just did as you say. but not work. but i just found some wrong things i did i am going to edit above code thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim i, fName, inputFldr, TmpFdr

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
inputFldr = Replace(wscript.scriptfullname,wscript.scriptname,"myFolder")
Set fldr = fso.getFolder(inputFldr)
i = 0
fName = 0
wscript.echo "Input Folder: " & fldr.path
For Each file In fldr.Files
    i = i + 1
    TmpFdr = inputFldr & "\" & fName & "\"
    if Not fso.FolderExists(TmpFdr) Then fso.CreateFolder (TmpFdr)
    file.move TmpFdr

    If i > 50 Then
        fName = fName + 1
        i = 0
    End If
Next
set fldr=nothing
set fso=nothing
```

Comment: It really Did work. thank you very much.
i really appreciate if any one could show me my mistakes.

Comment: `fso.FolderExists(fName)` does not know which folder `fName` is relative to, so it's always the best to have the full path. Have a read on [MSDN FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx). Please mark answer btw.